# Randomly mapping an image in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quite a bit of looking at this one.

I have an aspx web page with an Image control on it, and I want to load images from my web directory at random to diplay in the image control. The below is the code and how far I have got.

Seems a simple task to request an image file at random and display this in a web page, all I am receiving however is a local filepath (which appears to be no use to the Image Control) and no image on the webpage.

AppSettings.imageUrl returns: "~/Images"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetImage();
    }

    private void GetImage()
    {

        imgMain.ImageUrl = ResolveClientUrl(RandomImage());

    }
    private string RandomImage()
    {
        string mapPath = Request.MapPath(AppSettings.imageUrl);

        var rand = new Random();
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(mapPath);
        return files[rand.Next(files.Length)];
```

Comment: try prepending the application path to `mapPath` in `RandomImage()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RandomImage() method possibly doesn't return file path relative to current page. Either return

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file[rand.Next(files.Length)]);
return AppSettings.imageUrl + fileName;
```

and then resolve it or resolve it right away

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file[rand.Next(files.Length)]);
return Request.MapPath(AppSettings.imageUrl + fileName);
```

Comment: Sorry, @Nikola, but that wouldn't make sense because your two lines would return the following strings: (1) "~/imagesc:\\thepathofthefile.jpg" and (2) I don't know what this would return. Request.MapPath is supposed to get you the local path of ~/imagesC:\the path of the file?

Comment: Thanks Nikola, been working for a few hours today and I just couldnt see it! Used what you reccomended and just grabbed a list of filenames from the path in a for each loop, then just appended this to my image directory "~\Images\"

Comment: Hi Fabio. You are right, I apologize, I didn't check doc. Answer is now changed to include extracting file name.

Comment: Cool Nikola. It's a shame not even an upvote for helping others to improve their answers :)

Comment: ^^ that seems a better idea XD

Comment: Still learning my manners on StackOverflow :) Sorry once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a View Source on the resulting page and see if the `<img src="...">` is getting set to a sensible value.

On further investigation it seems that [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) takes a *relative* URL, not an absolute file system path. Therefore `RandomImage` should return something like:

```
return AppSettings.imageUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(files[rand.Next(files.Length)]);
```

Comment: the sensible value is that the image src is set to a local path (something like C:\whatever\path.jpg).

Comment: So - not very sensible then :-) See my update about `ResolveClientUrl`.

Comment: That's a fine solution too @Duncan Smart.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the file names. The Directory.GetFiles could also be used in non-web application and therefore it would make no sense to treat the files as relative to your website root.

What you can do is get the local path for root of your site like this:

```
string root = Request.MapPath("~/");
```

and then remove that substring from the file you selected:

```
files[rand.Next(files.Length)].Replace(root, string.Empty);
```

That's all you need.